# Value of a coercive polynomial along an algebraic curve

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $F(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be a coercive polynomial, that is, suppose that

$$\displaystyle \lim_{\max\{|x|, |y|\} \rightarrow \infty} F(x,y) = + \infty.$$

Let $G \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be and odd-degree polynomial. Consider the real plane curve $C_G : G(x,y) = 0$.

Suppose that $\gcd(F,G) = 1$, so in particular the curves $C_F, C_G$ do not share a common component. Does it follow that whenever $(x,y) \in C_G$ that $|F(x,y)| \gg \min\{|x|, |y|\}$?

Comment: I don't know a full answer, but I think you have to assume that $C_G$ and $C_F$ don't intersect. Eg take $F(x, y) = x^2+y^2-1$ and $G(x, y) = x-1/2$. They intersect in two points, both of which have two non-zero coordinates...